# android catch touches in background

Tags: android, background, overlay, gesture, touches

I want to provide user with a way to control my application then it is in background. I implemented special hidden area in a corner via overlay. But such solution has lots of restrictions: only 2 possible actions for each hidden area (one for regular touch and other for long press), other applications use the same behavior (area can be overlapped) etc.

While searching for alternatives I found the AGS application [here](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.benzul.ags).This application uses gesture and it catches them everywhere on the screen.

AFAIK it is impossible to do with overlay, Am I right? Any ideas how to implement such behavior?